# Check if class has been included

Tags: puppet

We have Puppet set specific firewall rules on our system administrator's workstations. We discovered recently that some systems were connected to the wrong network ports and were able to get admin access to things based on IP address. All of these systems are using Puppet, so we wanted to have Puppet fail if a system is on the admin network and doesn't have the correct firewall rules enabled.

This worked perfectly yesterday and now doesn't work today and I can't figure out why.

We have a factor that creates facts in the format `vlan####_interface: eth0` and `vlan###_ipaddress: 10.72.1.100` based on the IP addresses actually on the machine.

#### profile/manifests/firewall_rulesets/vlan2501.pp

```
class profile::firewall_rulesets::vlan2501 {

  firewall{"801 add some example firewall rule":
    ensure => present,
    chain  => 'INPUT',
    proto  => 'tcp',
    dport  => '22',
    source => ['10.72.1.0/24'],
    state  => ['NEW'],
    action => 'accept',
  }
}
```

#### profile/manifests/base.pp

```
class profile::base {
  ... other stuff ...

  Firewall {
    before  => Class['::fw::post'],
    require => Class['::fw::pre'],
  }

  include ::fw::pre
  include ::fw::post
}
```

#### fw/manifests/pre.pp

```
class fw::pre {
  Firewall {
    require => undef,
  }

  #ensure input rules are cleaned out, but ignore fail2ban
  firewallchain { 'INPUT:filter:IPv4':
    ensure => present,
    ignore => '-j f2b-sshd',
    purge  => true,
  }

  firewallchain { 'f2b-sshd:filter:IPv4':
    ignore => '-A f2b-sshd',
  }

  # Default firewall rules
  firewall { '000 accept all icmp':
    proto  => 'icmp',
    action => 'accept',
  }
  -> firewall { '001 accept all to lo interface':
    proto   => 'all',
    iniface => 'lo',
    action  => 'accept',
  }
  -> firewall { '002 reject local traffic not on loopback interface':
    proto       => 'all',
    iniface     => '! lo',
    destination => '127.0.0.1/8',
    action      => 'reject',
  }
  -> firewall { '003 accept related established rules':
    proto  => 'all',
    state  => ['RELATED', 'ESTABLISHED'],
    action => 'accept',
  }
}
```

#### fw/manifests/post.pp

```
class fw::post {
  firewall { '999 drop all':
    proto  => 'all',
    action => 'drop',
    before => undef,
  }

  # This is set to be after all other firewall rules by profile::base
  if $facts['vlan2501_ipaddress'] {
    if (! defined( Class['profile::firewall_rulesets::vlan2501'] )) {

      # We want to fail, not include the missing rules, because we want admins to be forced to verify all the other included manifests and make sure the machine is properly set up
      fail( "An interface with an IP address is on VLAN 2501, but does not have the correct firewall rules. ${facts['vlan2501_interface']} => ${facts['vlan2501_ipaddress']}" )
    }
  }
}
```

#### role/manifests/staff_workstation.pp

```
class role::my_example_machine {
  include ::profile::base
  include ::profile::firewall_rulesets::vlan2501
  ... other stuff ...
}
```

My understanding is that since `fw::post` is set to require all other `Firewall` actions, the check for `Class['profile::firewall_rulesets::admin_workstation']` should be true even though it is included after `profile::base`

Comment: You say it's not working, but what is the actual behavior? (Could you elaborate?) Is it not failing on systems on VLAN 2501, or does it fail every where? If possible include logs in Pastebin or something because this is difficult to reproduce without your custom Facts, etc. Also, leading colons in class names are no longer recommended since Puppet 4.x.

Comment: @AaronCopley Systems not on that VLAN always work fine. If I include `::profile::firewall_rulesets::vlan2501` before `::profile::base`, systems on that VLAN also work as expected. If I use the manifest mentioned in the question, it appears that the ordering rules don't matter and I always get the `fail()` message.